# how to read text file into array into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a new column that reads a file name from the column : df['Filename'] applies np.genfromtext and then puts the resulting array in a new column called Scan.

```
d = {'Filename':['G924310X.txt','G924330X.txt','G924340X.txt'],
 'Longitude':[92.4,92.4,92.4],    
 'Latitude':[-31.0,-33.0,-34.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

def f(x):
    return np.genfromtxt(x , delimiter=', ')

df['Scan'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(df['Filename']), axis = 1)
```

I get this error, 
TypeError: ("Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly", 'occurred at index 0')

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try `df['Scan'] = df['Filename'].apply(f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should change

```
df['Scan'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(df['Filename']), axis = 1)
```

for

```
df['Scan'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x['Filename'].item()), axis = 1)
```

Or maybe

```
df['Scan'] = df.Filename.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Otherwise `apply` will *always* call the function with your whole series for every row. The [`.item()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) func just pops out the unique elem in the series.